# Can click very far to the right of a beta site logo

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, user-interface, logo

I have checked a few beta sites and they are all like this.  When you click on "Puzzling beta" it takes you to the site's [front page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).  But you can move your mouse very far to the right of it (as far as the red X in the screenshot) and still click on it.

Non-beta sites are not like this - you have to click directly on the logo.  You can't move the mouse away from the logo and still click on it.

[image]

This is the web inspector highlighting:

[image]

And this is it with 100% width and height, and 10px padding, with the CSS changes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a problem? There is ample padding between the right edge of the link area and the questions link for accidental clicks to be very difficult…?

Comment: This isn't new behavior.

Comment: So... what?....

Comment: @nicael I've seen you report bugs a lot more insignificant than this!

Comment: I think its done intentionally keeping mobile devices/views in mind, but if thats the case why not keep the same for normal SE sites. :l

Comment: I normally click a header to focus the window, after messing around on my other screen. This has made me navigate away multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, all beta site should behave similarly instead of having varying width elements that can overflow or otherwise misbehave.