# Is there any way I can see if a questions has been bumped by Community?

Tags: support, community-user, bump

Some old questions are usually "edited" by Community profiles on the network sites, in order to get more attention if they meet certain criteria.

Is there a way to know that an old question has already been bumped by Community, or does the warning on the yellow board disappear after some time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, the message only shows up for a day or so (currently 1 day on Stack Overflow, 3 everywhere else). But, a history record is created when the post is bumped, so [you can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to find out when questions were bumped in the past](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/631713/recently-bumped-questions):

```
select top 500 -- only most recent 500 for this example; we're not that bored
 PostId [Post Link], CreationDate "Date Bumped"
from PostHistory
where PostHistoryTypeId=50
order by CreationDate desc
```

Caveat: [this history only goes back as far as May of 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110177/is-there-any-way-to-see-which-posts-community-has-bumped/279201#279201)

Comment: Hmm.. is it a day [or 3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288139/bumped-to-the-homepage-notices-should-link-to-community-users-profile#comment935635_288195)? Happy to quote you instead if Oded is wrong :)

Comment: Heh... The current setting is 1 day on Stack Overflow, but the default is 3 (so that applies to all other sites). Edited to note this.

Answer (score 3):

The community bump notice disappears after any activity or ages away after [three days of inactivity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288139/bumped-to-the-homepage-notices-should-link-to-community-users-profile#comment935635_288195) (or [one on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291414/307988)). You can see if a particular post has been bumped by looking at that post's timeline or revision list. You can see a post's timeline using the URL:

```
http://{site}/posts/{post-id}/timeline
```

or, revision list:

```
http://{site}/posts/{post-id}/revisions
```

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252100/can-click-very-far-to-the-right-of-a-beta-site-logo), for example, was recently bumped. You can see that it has been bumped twice in the last month...

[Timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/252100/timeline):

> [image]

[Revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/252100/revisions):

> [image]